# AppEngine Primary Keys

Tags: database, google-app-engine, primary-key, bigtable, unique-key

by default, GAE adds a unique key to your db entries.

Is it possible to have a numeric unique key in addition?

Elias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - the only value that App Engine enforces uniqueness on is its own key. You can use your own numeric key in place of the autogenerated one, though. How you do so depends on your platform; on Python you do something like the following:

```
my_entity = ModelClass(key=db.Key.from_path('ModelClass', 1234), ...)
```